# ADx analytics android integration issue

Tags: android

I try to integrate ADx mobile analytics into my android application. Maby something wrong with my AndroidManifest file. Can anyone provide me with rigth manifest integration. Thanks.

I have such error log:

```
02-09 13:33:38.328: E/AdXAppTracker(13547): Add APP_ID to AndroidManifest.xml file. For more detail integration document.


02-09 13:33:38.328: I/AdXAppTracker(13547): URL parameters: udid=&androidID=447b5493f5e9c26f&device_name=&device_type=&os_version=&country_code=&language=&app_id=&clientid=&app_version=&tag_version=2.0a&
02-09 

13:33:38.339: I/AdXAppTracker(13547): baseURL: http://ad-x.co.uk/atrk/android?


02-09 13:33:38.339: I/AdXAppTracker(13547): requestURL: http://ad-x.co.uk/atrk/android?udid=&androidID=447b5493f5e9c26f&device_name=&device_type=&os_version=&country_code=&language=&app_id=&clientid=&app_version=&tag_version=2.0a&




02-09 13:33:38.910: I/AdXAppTracker(13547): --------------------


02-09 13:33:38.921: I/AdXAppTracker(13547): response status: 200


02-09 13:33:38.929: I/AdXAppTracker(13547): response size: 62

02-09 13:33:38.933: I/AdXAppTracker(13547): response: 
02-09 13:33:38.933: I/AdXAppTracker(13547): <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Success>false</Success>
02-09 13:33:38.937: I/AdXAppTracker(13547): --------------------


02-09 13:33:38.953: E/AdXAppTracker(13547): AdX Connect call failed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maby my solution will be helpfull to anyone. So I was integrating this into the project on flash for Android. I have to write an native extention to include Ad-x analytics into my project. This error I got, because I have added xml properties to AndroidManifest.xml file, not in MyProj-app.xml file. When I added it into proper place - all works great.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the solution